# Apostol Finite Decimal Approximation Remark

Tags: real-analysis

Early on in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis he proves the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.20**. Assume $x \geq 0$. Then for every integer $n \geq 1$ there is a finite decimal $r_n = a_0.a_1a_2\cdots a_n$ such that $r_n \leq x < r_n + 1/10^n$.

Immediately after he remarks,

> It is easy to verify that $x$ is actually the supremum of the set of rational numbers $r_1, r_2, \dots$

I'm unsure how *easy* this verification is supposed to be at this stage in the text.

---

So far he's introduced

- well-ordering principle (for $\mathbf{N}$)
- supremum definition
- [least upper bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers#Least_upper_bound_property)
- **Theorem 1.1**. If $a,b \in \mathbf{R}$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $a < b + \epsilon$ then $a \leq b$.
- **Theorem 1.14 (Approximation property)**. Let $\emptyset \neq S \subset \mathbf{R}$ with $b = \sup S$. Then for $a < b$ there exists $x \in S$ such that $a < x \leq b$.
- **Theorem 1.18 (Archimedian property)**. For every $y \in \mathbf{R}$ there is a positive intger $n$ such that $n > y$.

Here's my proof using the above facts.

Let $a = \sup\{r_n\}$. Clearly $a \leq x$. We want to show $x \leq a$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. By theorem 1.18 with $y = 1/\epsilon$ there exists $N \geq 1$ such that $1 < N\epsilon$. By induction $n \leq 10^n$ for each $n \geq 1$. Thus $1 < 10^N \epsilon$ so that $1/10^N < \epsilon$. So we have $$x < r_N + 1/10^N \leq a + 1/10^N < a + \epsilon.$$ By theorem 1.1 it follows $x = a$.

Is this in line with the 'easy' verification Apostol was alluding to? Is there a simpler line of reasoning to show that $x = \sup\{r_n\}$?

Comment: I think you got it. However, out of style, I would just show that $x>r_n$ and that $x<r_n+\varepsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ without appealing to some least upper bound $a$. Hence by definition, $x$ is the least upper bound.